# How do you use "which" when asking a question

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, subject-verb-inversion, questions, do-support

I am wondering how to state this question and do not know which one is correct so is #1 correct or #2 correct or are they both grammatically fine?

1. Ferrous metals contain which element?
2. Which element do ferrous metals contain?

Comment: From the discussion below, the context of the question might make a difference as to which is more appropriate.

Comment: What does your research suggest?

Comment: Those voting to close this question should try googling for this reversal of inversion with interrogatives. I can't find anything readily.

Answer (score 4):

The [standard word order](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/beginner-grammar/question-forms-subjectobject-questions) for questions with an interrogative — *who (whom), why, where, which, what,* and *how* — places the interrogative or its phrase as the first element in a clause immediately followed by the verb:

> *What car* did she buy and *how much* did she end up paying?
>   *How* did they manage to get here on time?
>   *Who* did she go with to the concert?
>   *Where* are they going?

Using declarative rather than interrogative word order, as in your example, yields a style typical of quizzes or quiz shows:

> Lady Gaga teamed up with [*which famous crooner*](http://www.triviaquestionsnow.com/for/tv-trivia) to sing "Baby It's Cold Outside" for a Barnes & Noble bookstore commercial? — TV Trivia Questions and Answers | TQN
>
> Snoopy, from “The Peanuts”, is [*what breed*](http://www.triviaquestionsnow.com/question/what-kind-of-dog-is-snoopy) of dog? — TV Trivia Questions and Answers | TQN
>
> A Richter Scale reading of 7 is [*how many times*](https://studysoup.com/questions/biology/128626/a-richter-scale-reading-of-7-is-how-many-times-greater-that-a-reading-of-6) greater than a reading of 6? — StudySoup.

<sup>Answers: Tony Bennet, beagle, x10.</sup>

This construction is perfectly grammatical and in either oral (pub quiz) or written contexts emphasizes the essential question in the sentence.

In other situations, using declarative word order — which often places the interrogative in final position — also emphasizes the words essential to the question, but with differing verbal stress or tone, may express any number of emotional responses to a preceeding statement, especially surprise or disbelief:

> Statement: I hear Mark bought a Škoda.
>   Response: He bought a *what*?
>
> Possible Context: I’ve never heard the word *Škoda*, much less that it’s the name of a make of car.  Or with a different tone: What? Since I’ve known him he’s always driven a Ford truck. What made him change?
>
> Statement: The Smiths went to Lisbon for three weeks.
>   Response: They went *where*?
>
> Possible Context: The Smiths usually only travel to places where one or both of them speak the language. Or with a different tone: Wonderful! I’ve always wanted to go there. I hear the seafood is great!

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid, but the pedant in me says both should be clarified to ask for the element in common. For example:
Ferrous metals all contain which element?
Which element do all ferrous metals contain?

To avoid a facetious but correct answer along the lines of "Ferrous metals can contain numerous elements. For example many ferrous metals contain carbon, while others contain manganese, chromium, and nickel."

Comment: +1 for the pedantry: I have worked with large numbers of engineers who would deliberately exploit any possible ambiguity in questions or plans.

Comment: +1 I was thinking exactly the same thing about the example sentences in the question.